# Why do I get more than one SIGCHLD when I only called fork once?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

i'm studying signals in Linux and i'm trying to understand the mechanisms of processes. I Wrote this code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void filsFini(int sig){
  printf("The Child finished\n");
}

int main(){
  pid_t pid;
  system("clear");
  if((pid=fork())==0){
    printf("Child in a break\n");
    for(;;);
  }

  printf("The father %d \n",getpid());
  system("ps -lH");
  (void) signal(SIGCHLD,filsFini);
  printf("hit a button to end\n");
  getchar();
  kill(pid,SIGINT);
  system("ps -lH");
  waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
  system("ps -lH");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

at the end i get this result which i have one problem is that the `printf("Child finished\n");`is written twice how can i avoid that ?

Comment: I don't see any code that prints Child finished... Maybe you have another version?

Comment: It’s in the function filsFini that i use as a handler for the signal SIGCHLD

Comment: OK, so the task is to check that only the child process handles the signal call only once. Maybe you can use a static variable in filsFini, and initially it's 0. After the first call increase by 1, then don't print for the next calls?

Comment: Maybe..but i wanna know the reason why it’s called twice..because the child it becomes a Zombie then as soon as the child dies it sends a SIGCHLD to the father so it should be called only once..i think the waitpid is the reason but i don’t see it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `system("ps -lH");` will call `fork()` too, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html
2. If you want call `printf("Child finished\n");` only once, you could catch `SIGINT` in child process and output it.

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void handle_SIGINT(int sig) {
  printf("The Child finished\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(){

  signal(SIGINT, handle_SIGINT);

  pid_t pid;
  if ((pid=fork()) == 0) {
    printf("Child in a break\n");
    for(;;)
      ;
  }

  printf("The father %d \n", getpid());
  system("ps -lH");
  printf("hit a button to end\n");
  getchar();
  kill(pid, SIGINT);
  printf("\nbefore waitpid:\n");
  system("ps -lH");
  waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
  printf("\nafter waitpid:\n");
  system("ps -lH");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4):

You are creating additional children with each call to `system("ps -lH")`, and you get `SIGCHLD` notifications for them too.  Unfortunately, there isn't any way to control which child processes you receive `SIGCHLD` notifications for.  It's all or nothing.

For the program you have written, I would recommend you choose nothing: *don't install a handler for `SIGCHLD`*.  You can rely on the `waitpid` call that you already have, to notify you when the child process you directly created has finished.  `system` will take care of calling `waitpid` for the child processes it creates; you don't have to worry about them.

(The all-or-nothing nature of `SIGCHLD` is a major hassle when writing more complicated programs that need to wait for variable combinations of child process completions and asynchronous I/O events, especially if there are libraries involved that might create child processes that the main event loop doesn't know about.  But don't worry about that till you get there.)

Comment: Okay thanks..do you have an idea of how can i print only once « Child finished » just after sending signal Kill?

Comment: @AbdoRabah Put `printf("Child finished\n")` right after the `waitpid`, in `main`.